# Split itemize into multiple columns

Tags: itemize, multicol, columns

Is it possible to split an `itemize` list into several columns? (I'm sure it is, but I couldn't find a solution around here)

And additionally: Is it possible to automatically split a list into multiple columns if it reaches a certain item length?

For example, I want to display

```
item1
item2
item3
```

instead of

```
item1   item2   item3
```

while this should still happen:

```
item1   item4
item2   item5
item3   item6
```

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31565/same-indentation-of-itemize-and-itemize-in-columns?rq=1

Comment: What about page breaking if this `itemize` happens close to the page boundary?

Comment: This close to being a duplicate of [breaking a list into multiple columns in latex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398127/breaking-a-list-into-multiple-columns-in-latex).

Comment: @StrategyThinker Thank you for this useful resource. This is more or less the same solution as proposed by Peter Grill as answer. But it doesn't help solving the second part of my question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is some code that does the automatic column adjust thing, I used the code found in ["count and use the number of items in advance"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/count-and-use-the-number-of-items-in-advance) to help me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{countitems}
\newcounter{nextitemizecount}
\newcommand{\setupcountitems}{%
  \stepcounter{nextitemizecount}%
  \setcounter{countitems}{0}%
  \preto\item{\stepcounter{countitems}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\computecountitems}{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\number\c@countitems}%
  \label{countitems@\number\numexpr\value{nextitemizecount}-1\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\nextitemizecount}{%
  \getrefnumber{countitems@\number\c@nextitemizecount}%
}
\newcommand{\previtemizecount}{%
  \getrefnumber{countitems@\number\numexpr\value{nextitemizecount}-1\relax}%
}
\makeatother    
\newenvironment{AutoMultiColItemize}{%
\ifnumcomp{\nextitemizecount}{>}{3}{\begin{multicols}{2}}{}%
\setupcountitems\begin{itemize}}%
{\end{itemize}%
\unskip\computecountitems\ifnumcomp{\previtemizecount}{>}{3}{\end{multicols}}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Here are two columns
  \begin{AutoMultiColItemize}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
  \item Item 5
  \item Item 6
  \end{AutoMultiColItemize}
  \item AutoMultiColItemize can be nested in an itemize
  \item Or it does not have to be.
  \item Normal itemize, like this one, are still single column.
\end{itemize}
Here is one column
\begin{AutoMultiColItemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{AutoMultiColItemize}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Multiple Columns]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great solution! This makes documents with many lists definitely cleaner. As a Tex beginner, all this stuff is a new world to discover and I love it how fast one can get perfect help around the stackexchange network. Awesome Stackexchange folks =)!

Comment: Great effort Strategy Thinker. Still one problem though, the items are not vertically aligned. Items of the right column are closer!! It becomes clearer if you add `Item 4` in the last list.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add a `\unskip` after `\end{itemize}`, otherwise it would create a new line.

Comment: The image illustrating the result doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @usernumber I restored that image using the wayback machine on web.archive.org

Comment: Could you do this but instead of the numbers going down could you have the numbers going across

Answer (score 214):

Since you want multiple columns, you should use [the `multicol` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
Two columns:
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
    
Three columns:
    \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What can happen if you have an item with long text? Sure it will extend to the next column. What is the solution in this case?

Comment: @AboAmmar: I am not sure I fully understand the problem you are describing. Please edit your question and provide a test case ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)) that illustrates what you are describing and what you think the "correct" output should be.

Comment: as much as it pains me to say, but multicol is not a good solution to this problem in a general case. It works alright in your examples above, because they all contain single line items and the same in each column, but this gets bad the moment you have different amounts of text per column. As multicol starts with slighly compressed column heights and works its way up to the point they balance you normally end up with uneven (and compressed glue and that can look rather horrible. See my talk from Tokyo 2013 (http://latex-project.org/papers/) where I discuss some of those issues.

Comment: (for the lazy, the slides from the 2013 talk are at https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2013-10-23-FMi-stony-beamer.pdf). Any progress since this talk on that question, @FrankMittelbach ?

Answer (score 32):

Use `multicol`. If your items do not divide evenly into each column, add `\item[\vspace{\fill}]` to the end of your list to align the items.

---

The `multicol` package solution from [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194455/) works well if your enumerate items can be divided evenly into each column.

However, spacing between items can become inconsistent if each column does not hold an equal number of items. For example, dividing 7 items between 2 columns:

[image]

One can fix this easily by adding an 'empty' item at the end of the list as padding.

```
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
```

Which produces the following nicely aligned multi-columned enumerate list:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one  \item two \item three \item four
    \item five \item six \item seven \item[\vspace{\fill}]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A very useful answer, especially about the spacing bit. But, suppose the items are multiline, and differenly so, is there a way one can cause 1 to align with 5, 2 with 6, and so on so that each line across from one another always start on the same line of text?

(for reference, I have two separate enumerate envs, so they both number the same, so its really 1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc)

Answer (score 11):

A quick possible solution is using the `minipage` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
    \item item 6
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Comment: I would note that this quickly becomes unmaintainable and doesn't purely represent the idea of columns.

Comment: @Sean Allred- However, using two `minipage`s will change how list items are numbered (column-wise rather than row-wise, as desired). Only the second part of the question hasn't been answered. None of the other 3 answers succeeded in this regard.

Comment: Try it with `enumerate` instead.

Comment: Good point about the desired behavior though; you're right in that `multicol` will always use as little vertical space as possible.  Perhaps a better question to ask, in this case, is if it is possible to give the `multicols` environment a minimum vertical space to occupy.  **Edit:** I spoke too soon; see the accepted answer `:)`

Comment: I didn't know you could have a ``minipage`` inside ``itemize``... it didn't work for me (beamer class), but of course having ``itemize`` inside ``minipages`` worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, you can do that with the `tasks` package, that was formerly part of the `exsheets` bundle. If you  use MiKTeX, beware it requires the `cntformats` package (from the same author), that's *not* (yet) part of MiKTeX. 
To answer Werner's question, it can break across pages.Here is an example of how it works:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[noheadfoot, nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tasks}
 \DeclareInstance{tasks}{myitemize}{default}
 {
enumerate = false ,
label-width = 1.125em,
label-offset = 0.6em,
label-format = \bfseries\color{IndianRed3}
 }

\settasks{style = myitemize, column-sep = 2em}%
\pagestyle{plain}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
    \task First item
    \task A second item
    \task A third one
    \task A second series, item 1
    \task Second series, item 2
    \task Second series, item 3
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution would use the `shortlst` package, which is not part of any distribution for license reasons, so that you have to install it yourself. I patched it so as to be able to choose the number of columns with a key `nc=value` (3 by default) and the interline stretch `il=value` (1.33 by default).

The main advantage of this package is that if an item is longer than the column width it `automatically` spreads over two (or more) columns. Alternatively an item can be put in a parbox of width column width. I introduced a `\paritem` command, that takes as an optional argument the number of columns the item will spread over.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[nohead, nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\pagestyle{plain}%

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{shortlst, setspace, xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.33]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\quad\textbullet}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{Tomato3}{\bfseries\textbullet}}
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortitemize}}%
{\end{shortitemize}
 }%
 \newcommand\paritem[2][2]{\item \parbox[t]{\dimexpr#1\shortitemwidth + (2\labelsep + \labelwidth)*\numexpr#1-1\relax}{\setstretch{1}#2}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1 cm}

\begin{tabitemize}
    \item First item
    \item A second, much longer item
    \item A third, short item
    \paritem[2]{A second series, with a much longer item. \lipsum[2]}%
    \item Second series, item 4\strut
    \item Second series, third item, a much much longer item\strut
    \item Second series, fourthr item\strut
\end{tabitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While I like the `tasks` package (obviously) it does not do what the OP wants: items are arranged per *row* instead of per *column*. (BTW: *items* cannot contain page breaks)

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I misread, due to the fact the solutions are better known in that case. Should I withdraw my answer?

Comment: No, I'm sure it'll be useful for people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript code for [TeXstudio macro](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) that can do from this

```
One, two, three,
B is for bee. One, two,
The bee is near you.
```

automatically to this ([`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package is required)

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \item One, two, three,
        \item B is for bee. One, two,
        \item The bee is near you.
    \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
```

Maximal number of columns and enviroment (`enumerate` or `itemize`) can be chosen by `colmax` and `type` variables.

```
%SCRIPT
var colmax = 4; //maximal number of columns
var type = 0; //0 for enumerate, 1 for itemize
var lt, c, d, n, out;
var txt = cursor.selectedText();
if (type == 0) lt = 'enumerate';
else lt = 'itemize';
function srch(re, str) {
       if (str.search(re) != -1)
          return 1;
       else
          return 0;}
var itarr = [srch(/enumerate/g, txt), srch(/itemize/g, txt), srch(/item/g, txt)]
var sum = itarr.reduce(add, 0);
function add(a, b) {return a + b;}
if (sum == 2)
    c = 2, d = 2;
    else if (sum == 1)
        c = 1, d = 0;   
    else {
        c = 0, d = 0;
        txt=txt.replace(/\n/g, '\n\\item ');}
txt.replace('\t','');
n = txt.split('\n').length-d;
for (n; n>colmax; n = 0.5*n);
n = Math.round(n);
cursor.removeSelectedText();
var p = ['\\begin{'+lt+'}\n', '\\begin{multicols}{'+n+'}\n', '\\item ', txt, '\n\\end{multicols}', '\n\\end{'+lt+'}'];
if (c == 2) out = [p[1], p[3], p[4]];
else if (c == 1) out = [p[0], p[1], p[3], p[4], p[5]];
else out = p;
editor.write(out.join(''));
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It seems like your answer uses code from another language besides LaTeX - could you indicate what it is and what part of the LaTeX code it produces?

Comment: It's written on javascript, i've edited my post. Latex examples inserted at the top. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, looks good (I wasn't aware TeXstudio could read JavaScript macros! But now I know). However, it seems your answer has the same problem as Peter's, namely distributing everything across 3 columns, whereas OP wanted to fill out one column before starting the next.