# Itemize text in a table

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I have such a table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}

    Feature eines Signales   & Feature eines Bildes                \\ \hline\hline
     Der Peak vom Spektral        &  Der Peak vom Spektral   \\ 
    Der Peak von der Autokorrelation &  Die Größe des Bildes  \\ 

    Die Amplitude eines Signals  & Der Durchschnitt der Lichtstärke \\ 
    Nulldurchgang                & Die Fläche der Farbkomponente   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Die mögliche Features eines Signales und eines Bildes.\cite{kz4}} 
\end{table}
```

How can I itemize text in both column?

Comment: What do you mean by `itemize`?

Comment: In each cell of each column?

Comment: Use Package `booktabs` to make it more pleasing to the eye: `\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Feature eines Signales   & Feature eines Bildes                \\
\midrule
Der Peak vom Spektral        &  Der Peak vom Spektral   \\ 
Der Peak von der Autokorrelation &  Die Größe des Bildes  \\ 

Die Amplitude eines Signals  & Der Durchschnitt der Lichtstärke \\ 
Nulldurchgang                & Die Fläche der Farbkomponente
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}`

Comment: @Bernard yes at each cell of each columns

Comment: Are you sure a table is the best solution? A column-wise itemize environment might be an alternative. See my answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194426/split-itemize-into-multiple-columns/194437#194437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, textcomp}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll} \toprule Feature eines Signales & Feature eines
      Bildes \\ \midrule 
    \textbullet{} Der Peak des Spektrals & \textbullet{} Der Peak des Spektrals \\
    \textbullet{}  Der Peak der Autokorrelation & \textbullet{} Die Größe
    des Bildes \\ 

    \textbullet{} Die Amplitude eines Signals & \textbullet{} Der Durchschnitt der Lichtstärke \\
    \textbullet{} Nulldurchgang & \textbullet{} Die Fläche der Farbkomponente \\
    \bottomrule \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

However, »Peak *des* Spektrals« sounds correct.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly improved variant, that prevents having to write `textbullet` for each cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcommand\head[1]{ \multicolumn{1}{l}{\phantom{\textbullet\hskip\itemsep}#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{>{\textbullet\hskip\itemsep}l}@{}}
   \head{\hskip-\tabcolsep Feature eines Signales}   & \head{Feature eines Bildes}               \\ [3pt]
    \toprule\midrule
     Der Peak vom Spektral        &  Der Peak vom Spektral   \\
    Der Peak von der Autokorrelation &  Die Größe des Bildes  \\

    Die Amplitude eines Signals  & Der Durchschnitt der Lichtstärke \\
    Nulldurchgang                & Die Fläche der Farbkomponente   \\[3pt]
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Die mögliche Features eines Signales und eines Bildes.\cite{kz4}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]