# How do I make a 2-column bullet list?

Tags: two-column, bullets

How can I type this in latex ? I can only do 1 column

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Module
\item Loss
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: use table with two columns (for each itemize one)?

Comment: a table, or just two minipages, each with a list, or a two column document.

Comment: I recommend you change the title of your question so that it is more descriptive. That way other users may find your question more easily in the future. I suggest "How do I make a 2-column bullet list?"

Comment: @kong Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split itemize into multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194426/split-itemize-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 7):

My way would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test 2
\end{itemize}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\begin{itemize}
\item test 3
\item test 4
\item test 5
\end{itemize}
\vfill\null
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

leading to
[image]

Answer (score 5):

To keep the items in each list together in the source, I suggest using `minipage`.

[image]

You can adjust the widths (currently set at 4cm) if you prefer the two lists be closer or farther apart. Note the `[t]` option, which aligns the `minipage`s at the top rather than the default center.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
    \underline{Abstract Classes}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Module
        \item Loss
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
    \underline{Inherited Classes}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item MSELoss
        \item ReLu, Tanh
        \item Linear
        \item Sequential
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

If you want the bullets to be flush left and the spacing reduced between the items (as in your example) you can use the `enumitem` package

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

and then add options at the beginning of each list:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is closer to what you're looking for, bullets within a `tabular` environment. My answer is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150650/121944).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
    \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \underline{Abstract Classes} & \underline{Inherited Classes} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \tabitem Module & \tabitem MSELoss \\
    \tabitem Loss   & \tabitem ReLu, Tanh \\
                    & \tabitem Linear \\
                    & \tabitem Sequential \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]