# two items in one line with itemize

Tags: itemize

I have the below list, but i want item a & b to be in the same lline, is there a way to do that?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item [$\rightarrow$]<1> a. 
\item [$\rightarrow$]<2> b.
\item [$\rightarrow$]<3> c.
\item [$\rightarrow$]<4> d.
\item [$\rightarrow$]<5> g 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Uhm, your use of `<1>`, `<2>`, ... suggests that you are using `beamer`...

Comment: Yes I’m using it in Beamer

Comment: That was not obvious from your question, thus our standard comment for new users: please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have no idea about document class (we now know this is `beamer`) plus appropriate preamble.

Answer (score 1):

if what you want is to replace the items, you can use "only":

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\only<1>{\item [$\rightarrow$] a.}
\only<2>{\item [$\rightarrow$] b.}
\only<3>{\item [$\rightarrow$] c.}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0):

For items in two columns `tasks` is an easy solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tasks}[label=$\rightarrow$](2)
\task a \pause
\task b \pause
\task c \pause
\task d \pause
\task g \pause
\end{tasks}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

if you want to see other ways of doing this you can see, for example, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194426/split-itemize-into-multiple-columns).