# Configure the bullets of a list created with the tasks package

Tags: beamer, itemize, themes, tasks

I want to split the content of a bulleted list in a beamer presentation into several columns. Apparently this can be be easily acomplished through a `tasks` environment. My problem is that the bullets produced by `tasks` are different to those produced by `itemize`. This is what I have attempted so far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tasks}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=RoyalBlue}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}\usesubitemizeitemtemplate{%
    \tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{beamerstructure}$\blacktriangleright$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
        Itemize:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item foo
            \item bar
            \item baz
        \end{itemize}
        Tasks:
        \begin{tasks}[label=\textbullet](3)
        %\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](3)  % ERROR
        %\begin{tasks}[label=\labelitemi](3)  % ERROR
            \task foo
            \task bar
            \task baz
        \end{tasks}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the output I get:
[image: Output]
If I try any of the commented options the following error is thrown:

```
...
! Undefined control sequence.
\thetask ->\labelitemi 
                       
l.25 \end{frame}
                
?
```

How could I obtain exactly the same bullets?

Comment: Might work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194455/250119 (didn't test)

Comment: `multicols` did the trick. Thank you, @user202729.

Comment: I flag question as duplicate then.

Comment: The link you provided is a useful workaround, but does not really answer the question

Comment: If you want it to look exactly like itemize, why don't you just use itemize? With `\begin{multicols}{3} ... \end{multicols}{3}` around it, it will also be arranged in 3 columns.

Answer (score 2):

#### Adaptations

- changed color to `blue`, because `RoyalBlue` is not defined
- defined a command `\tball` that draw a shaded ball with tikz
- set `label-format=\tball`
- set `label` and `label-width`

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}\usesubitemizeitemtemplate{%
    \tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{beamerstructure}$\blacktriangleright$}%
}

\newcommand{\tball}{\tikz \shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \texttt{itemize} within \texttt{multicols}:
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \texttt{tasks}:
    \begin{tasks}[label-format=\tball, label={}, label-width=8pt](3)
    \task foo
    \task bar
    \task baz
    \end{tasks}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```