# Suppress vertical offset before columns environment

Tags: tables, beamer, verbatim, columns

The columns environment, combined with `tabular` and `verbatim` seems to create a huge vertical offset to the text, which I don't know how to get rid of:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Irgendeine Überschrift}
Etwas sinnloser Text, der länger als eine Zeile werden soll und deshalb noch ein paar Wörter braucht.
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
Blabla1
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
Blabla2
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Beispiel für eine Tabelle}
Etwas sinnloser Text, der länger als eine Zeile werden soll und deshalb noch ein paar Wörter braucht.
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
\begin{table}
\caption{Chemische Elemente}
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
\toprule
OZ & Element & MZ \\
\midrule
1 & H & 1 \\
2 & He & 4 \\
3 & Li & 7 \\
4 & Be & 9 \\
5 & B & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
\toprule
OZ & Element & MZ \\
\midrule
1 & H & 1 \\
2 & He & 4 \\
3 & Li & 7 \\
4 & Be & 9 \\
5 & B & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{verbatim}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: bco1]

Without the `table` environment, the vertical alignment is even worse!
[image: bco2]

Also, the text inside the columns is not properly horizontally aligned to the  text before. Although this has been adressed [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7452), there was no real solution as to [which value to use for the column widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7442/margins-in-beamer-columns#comment12345_7452).

Do you have any suggestions how to suppress the vertical offset between text and `columns`, and ideally have the columns also horizontally aligned to the text?

Comment: Both `verbatim` and the `table` environment uses internally a list (`table` as it calls `center`). Cancelling spaces added by lists can be a complete pain, even more as \addvspace is involved. 
Additionally you are using a `\caption` (which inserts a space above), this doesn't make it easier. I would simply use `\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}` before the columns to adjust the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress the space above `verbatim` by adding `\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}` after loading `etoolbox` library. Also there naturally is some default space above captions (about 10pt), you can control this space by adding some suitable value like: `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-.5\baselineskip}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim, booktabs}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Irgendeine Überschrift}
Etwas sinnloser Text, der länger als eine Zeile werden soll und deshalb noch ein paar Wörter braucht.
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
Blabla1
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
Blabla2
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Beispiel für eine Tabelle}
Etwas sinnloser Text, der länger als eine Zeile werden soll und deshalb noch ein paar Wörter braucht.
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-.5\baselineskip}
\begin{table}
\caption{Chemische Elemente}
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
\toprule
OZ & Element & MZ \\ \midrule
1  & H  & 1  \\
2  & He & 4  \\
3  & Li & 7  \\
4  & Be & 9  \\
5  & B  & 11 \\   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
%
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
\toprule
OZ& Element & MZ\\ 
\midrule
1 & H  & 1  \\
2 & He & 4  \\
3 & Li & 7  \\
4 & Be & 9  \\
5 & B  & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{verbatim}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(This answer is exclusively about the second `frame` environment in your posting. I'm not sure what the purpose of the first `frame` environment is.)

It appears that the `columns` environment adds a bit of vertical padding between itself and the material (if any) that precedes it. If you really don't want this padding -- which, at any rate, I would not call "huge" -- simply use side-by-side `minipage` environments (of width `0.5\textwdith`).

Incidentally, do note that it's in general quite pointless to use `table` environments in a `beamer` document. Don't use 'em.

The horizontal line in the following screenshot (generate by an `\hrule` instruction) is there merely to illustrate that no vertical padding is inserted if `minipage` environments are used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Beispiel für eine Tabelle}

Etwas sinnloser Text, der länger als eine Zeile werden 
soll und deshalb noch ein paar Wörter braucht.
\hrule % just to illustrate width of entire textblock
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
Chemische Elemente

\begin{tabular}{rlr}
\toprule
OZ & Element & MZ \\
\midrule
1 & H & 1 \\
2 & He & 4 \\
3 & Li & 7 \\
4 & Be & 9 \\
5 & B & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}% <--- "%" is important
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
\toprule
OZ & Element & MZ \\
\midrule
1 & H & 1  \\
2 & He & 4 \\
3 & Li & 7 \\
4 & Be & 9 \\
5 & B & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first frame is mainly there to show that this vertical offset does not occur with pure text inside `columns`. And that the running text and the text inside `columns` are not properly horizontally aligned.
I know tables are not that convenient for a `beamer` presentation, but this particular case is intended to show LaTeX novices how to code a table...