# Same (multi) columns width with different margins in Beamer

Tags: beamer, margins, columns

I am using Modern Theme from https://github.com/matze/mtheme. When I try to use double column for one slide, the size of the margins are different. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction: Current Government - Political Change}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Political Change: Ministry Creation}
{\small \begin{itemize}
\item Ministry of Family, Community, Cooperative and Associative Economy. 
        \begin{itemize}
        \item  Work for the multiplication, strengthening, development and promotion of the Small Business of the Family Economy. 
        \item Focus on: Tourism, gastronomy, handicrafts, production of the family agriculture and services to the tourism.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\vrule{}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{Characteristics of the self-employed workers:}
    {\small \begin{itemize}
    \item Ministry of Family, Community, Cooperative and Associative Economy. 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}}
    \end{center}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And my results are:

[image]

This is another slide with the same problem: [image]

What can I do to get the same margins?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two columns of `.5\textwidth` each cannot fit on a slide, as there is some distance between the columns. Either use `onlytextwidth` or smaller columns or even better both.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{your frame}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{onlytextwidth}
    \begin{columns}[t, onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{smaller columns}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter. Maybe I didn't explain myself in a proper way. I want the same width per each column, but the right size margin is way smaller than my left size margins. However, I haven't modified the size of the margin. Please check the updated post with another slide that I have done.

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez If your right margin is smaller, your columns are too wide. Try with `\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}`